# Nested associations - elasticsearch-rails or chewy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I have a Rails app with ActiveRecord models that have associations between them.

For the sake of simplicity, lets say I have exactly the same DB schema as in - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/blob/master/elasticsearch-model/examples/activerecord_associations.rb#L95

And I would want to search for Article author named 'John'.

`Article.search('john')` searches in *article.authors*' specified fields first_name and last_name as expected.

**I want to be more specific and say search from Article through article.authors by first_name only.**

`Article.search(authors: {first_name: 'john'})` does not work.

What is the correct way to do the above?

Also using Elastic HQ, in the articles index there's field *authors*. Does that mean that the elasticsearch-rails indexing is correct and nested authors?  [image: elastic hq article mapping]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you have accessible and working ElasticSearch instance. If you want to use queries with nested entities you have to use interfaces provided by `chewy` gem i.e. define custom index field. Here is example from [vanilla documentation](https://github.com/toptal/chewy#index-definition). First of all you need to create `/app/chewy/article_index.rb`

```
class ArticleIndex < Chewy::Index
  define_type Article.published.includes(:author_name) do
    # `published` above is example scope of published-only articles
    # I guess you may have :title and :body fields in model
    field :title, :body
    # Here is custom index field with *full* author name.
    # We use lambda to extract it from article:
    field :author_name, value: ->(article) { "#{article.author.first_name} #{article.author.last_name}" }
  end
end
```

Now query it as:

```
UsersIndex.query(text: {author_name: 'John'})
# or
UsersIndex.query(text: {author_name: 'Smith'})
# or even ...
UsersIndex.query(text: {author_name: 'John Smith'})
```

More readings:

- [`chewy` gem documentation](https://github.com/toptal/chewy)
- amazing Toptal [article](http://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/elasticsearch-for-ruby-on-rails-an-introduction-to-chewy)

Cheers!

Comment: After giving enough time for other people, I'm accepting your answer. I chose ElasticSearch-Rails for the work project, but for a personal project I went with Chewy. I might say Chewy is better in the long run. We might switch to Chewy after 6 months :)